# Can a twisted or 3 dimensional curve have an asymptote?

Tags: asymptotics, 3d, algebraic-curves, curves, plane-curves

Also,
I recently encountered a definition for 'asymptotes' in an old engineering mathematics book that says,"An asymptote is a straight line which cuts a curve in **two points** at an infinite distance from the origin and yet is not itself wholly at infinity.".

I understand very well that this definition is outdated as per modern authors. Yet, I had trouble understanding what does it mean by the use of the terms 'cuts a curve in two points'.

What prompted me to ask the question in the title is, I think by using the terms 'two points' the author might have meant the plane curve (2D). Thus I want to know if the concept of asymptotes can be applied to 3D curves.

Comment: I can’t find the connection between title and OP.

Comment: added explanation: "What prompted me to ask the question in the title is, I think by using the terms 'two points' the author might have meant the plane curve (2D). Thus I want to know if the concept of asymptotes can be applied to 3D curves.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the function $f(x)$ and an asymptote $a(x)=mx+n$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} \frac{f(x)}{mx}=1 \quad \lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(x)-mx=n$$

in this sense we can say that they “intersect at the two points at $\infty$ distance” but of course that is not a rigorous way to express this fact.

Of course we could have also asymptotes for a curve in 3D and also in this case we can have no more than two “intersection point at $\infty$”. Indeed this depends upon the fact that the straight line and curves are one dimensional.

Comment: It is not a definition, I’ve assumed a(x) as a given asymptote, thus it is a straight line.

Comment: $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ has $a(x)=1$ as an asymptote, but $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{a(x)}\ne1$.

Comment: An asymptote is a straight line. Which means it can only have one point of intersection with the given curve at infinity. For two such points there would be a pair of asymptotes.

Comment: Yes of course, I was trying to give evidence of the intersection in a simple way but of course my try was completely wrong! I fix, thanks!